Upload files to onedrive with php
I've been trying to load data onto my OneDrive using PHP for a long time.
I've already read a lot about this and also found a project on github.
Now I tried this tutorial, but I can't get any further.
https://www.webshark.ee/how-to-upload-files-from-server-to-microsoft-onedrive-using-rest-api-and-php/
I create a app in microsoft azure, to get the client id and more..
I downloaded the package with composer.
composer requires microsoft/microsoft-graph
I then created my script based on the first example in the tutorial. What I don't know is how to integrate the vendor from composer
my script looks like:
$tenantId = 'your-id-number';
$clientId = 'your-client-id-number';
$clientSecret = 'your-client-secret-number';
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token';
$user_token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'your-email@email.com',
        'password' => 'your-password'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$user_accessToken = $user_token->access_token;

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($user_accessToken);
?>

Currently I only get an error message when running the first script
Warning: Undefined variable $guzzle in C:\xampp_neu\htdocs\test1\src\test.php on line 6

Are oyu sure this problem is in any way related to Charts or Composer? To me, it looks obvious that the script does not run, as you haven't declared $guzzle anywhere (as the error message told you)

Guzzle is a HTTP client for PHP, and this warning is telling you that the Guzzle client is not defined. There are several steps to remedy this.
First, install it via Composer by running the following:
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

Second, in order to use Composer packages in your PHP script, you'll need to include the Composer autoloader at the top of the file. This will load all of the packages you're using in the current script while skipping any installed packages that won't be used:
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

And last, you'll need to instantiate the Guzzle client before its first usage:
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

Unrelated to your question, but you'll notice a further error unless you use the fully qualified namespace for the Graph() class:
$graph = new Microsoft\Graph\Graph();


okay, io tried it. now the request works, but i get a bad request for authent.

Glad to hear you're making progress! It looks like the tutorial you're using is several years old, so I'd consider looking at the official PHP/Graph tutorial from Microsoft instead. If you run into trouble that tutorial can't answer, you could ask a new question here.

what i don't know, is: how can i get the redirect url. this is empty in my azure portal
